# Fitting 20 values into 5 bits

Tags: math, binary-data

I need to store 20 different values into 5 bits but I fail to find a good mapping function for that.

An object can have up to 3 slots, each slot having a size of 1, 2, or 3. The order does not matter.

This can be represented in 2 ways:

- an array of length 3 where ar(0) = the size of slot #1, ar(1) = size of slot #2, etc. where a size of 0 means the slot is missing ;
- because the order does not matter, an array of length 3 where ar(0) = the number of size-1 slots, ar(1) = the number of size-2 slots, etc.

For example, an object having 2x size-3 slots and 1x size-1 slot would be [3,3,1] using the first representation or [1,0,2] using the second representation.

Since the order doesn't matter, [3,3,1], [3,1,3], and [1,3,3] are the same (1st rep). That's a total of 20 combinations.

So far, I can map this to 6 bits using the following simple formula:

```
N = 13 * #slot3 + 4 * #slot2 + #slot1
```

With the given example, that would be 2*13 + 1 = 27.

Reversing is done with:

```
#slot3 = N / 13
#slot2 = (N % 13) / 4
#slot1 = (N % 13) % 4
```

As said before, that ranges from 0 (no slot at all) to 3*13=39 (3x slot3) with gaps which requires 6 bits.

How can I fit this into 5 bits without using a map or a big switch/case?

Comment: using a lookup table is still faster since you don't need to do the slow divisions

Comment: A map/lookup table will surely works but I'm trying to lower memory access to a strict minimum. Not mentionned in the OP, I'm processing billions of objects and that takes a lot of time. When I tried to multithread it, I got a big performance drop, most probably because there are very few computations but huge memory I/Os (the ram becoming a bottleneck). So I'm trying fit all I can in the cache to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 20 ordered combinations of values 0,1,2,3 and want to find easy way of numbering these combinations and retrieving combinations by number.

For combinations, sorted descending, there are 10 combinations starting from 3, 6 combinations starting from 2, 3 combinations starting from 1 and one zero combination. These values are "triangular numbers". At the second stage (second combination item) values 4,3,2,1 are involved ("linear numbers"). Seems you don't want hold them in a table, so all values might be calculated "on the fly".

This is Python example of finding number of combination `num()` and retrieveing combination by number `retr()`

```
   def num(lst):
    lst.sort(reverse=True)
    n = 0
    j = 0
    for i in range(lst[0] + 1):
        j += i
        n += j
    for i in range(lst[1] + 1):
        n = n + i
    n = n + lst[2]
    return n

def retr(num):
    result = []
    i = 0
    j = 1
    k = 1
    while num >= k:
        j += i
        k += j
        num -= k
        i += 1
    num += k - j
    result.append(i)
    i = 0
    while num > i:
        i += 1
        num -= i
    result.append(i)
    result.append(num)
    return result

for i in range(20):
    comb = retr(i)
    print(comb, num(comb))

[0, 0, 0] 0
[1, 0, 0] 1
[1, 1, 0] 2
[1, 1, 1] 3
[2, 0, 0] 4
[2, 1, 0] 5
[2, 1, 1] 6
[2, 2, 0] 7
[2, 2, 1] 8
[2, 2, 2] 9
[3, 0, 0] 10
[3, 1, 0] 11
[3, 1, 1] 12
[3, 2, 0] 13
[3, 2, 1] 14
[3, 2, 2] 15
[3, 3, 0] 16
[3, 3, 1] 17
[3, 3, 2] 18
[3, 3, 3] 19
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks a lot for the implementation.